# Setup IIS Identity in an ApplicationPool using cmd or ps1

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

is there an example of setting the Identity in IIS for a Custom User in an Application Pool using command line or powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following appcmd.exe command line to set an identity in IIS for a custom user in the applicationpool.

```
appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.userName:DOMAIN\USER_NAME /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.password:PASSWORD
```

Here is my test steps and result:

1.Run cmd as administrator

2.Change directory to the location where appcmd.exe resides (c:\windows\system32\inetsrv):

`cd %WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv`

[image: image1]

3.Then enter the appcmd.exe command line, you need to replace the content in the red box.
[image: image2]

4.Then you can see that the application pool identity is successfully set as a custom account.
[image: image3]

Hope my answer can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$AppPoolName" -Name processModel -Value @{userName=$AppPoolUser;password=$AppPoolUserPw;identitytype=3}
```

See documentation for `processModel` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/processModel#configuration